# Getting "Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Just getting a Syntax Error, "Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse"

```
var trivia;
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=15&difficulty=easy&type=boolean');
 request.send();

trivia = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(trivia);
```

Comment: The HTTP request is **asynchronous**. You have to wait for it via an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to wait for the response to arrive before continuing on. You can achieve just that using the AJAX request's `onload` event:

```
var trivia;
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=15&difficulty=easy&type=boolean');


request.onload = function() {
    trivia = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(trivia);
}

request.send();
```